# How can I lower CruiseControl.NET's CPU usage?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cpu-usage

In our Cruise Control setup we have 171 projects. On the build server, the CC.NET Service Runner is always using over 67% CPU. That process has 200 threads.

A [thread](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CC-696) references a similar problem in the Java Version that they fixed by setting the interval.

Our intervalTrigger set like this: `<intervalTrigger seconds="60" />`

How do I get the CPU usage down or find out what CC.NET is doing?

Comment: Increase the interval, decrease logging level or get a better PC

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the logging. We have it turned off on our CCNet server.

Another solution is if you are polling against your source control you can redesign it using non polling route. For example with Subversion you can set up post commit hook to execute CCNet build node. Reducing the polling helps lower the CPU.